# Twitter Bootstrap - Enhance Navbar Content to the Maximum

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following:

[image]

Basically, I want the text "Home" to begin in line with the edge of the car picture. The last nav item should end on the right´. The Navbar is placed inside of a container-fluid. All li-elements between "Home" and "Inscriptions & Contact" should be centered. How can I accomplish that?

My Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default text-uppercase">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-first"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Instructeurs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Véhicules</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Examen &amp; Liens</a></li>
        <li class="nav-last"><a href="#">Inscriptions &amp; Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

And this is what I changed in my custom css file:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: MyriadPro;
    src: url("../fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf");
}


.navbar {
  font-family: "MyriadPro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: inherit !important;
  border-color: none !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav > li > a {
  padding-right: 50px !important;
  padding-left: 50px !important;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}

.active {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #8D1917 !important;
}
```

Comment: @makshh Woops, sorry! Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this using table layout (similar to [`btn-group-justified`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified) in Bootstrap).

CSS:

```
.container-fluid > .navbar-collapse,
.container-fluid > .navbar-header,
.container > .navbar-collapse,
.container>.navbar-header {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.navbar-nav-justified {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.navbar-nav-justified > li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/JXRMoR)**